# Problem mirroring Bitbucket repo to GCP Cloud Source Repo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm attempting to setup CICD for a GCP Cloud Function and App-Engine deployment. The repo is in Bitbucket and I am following the instructions found [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository) to create a mirror between my Bitbucket repo and a GCP Cloud Source repo.

Using the GCP Cloud Source "[Connect external repository](https://source.cloud.google.com/repo/connect)" UI I am able to select my GCP project, select Bitbucket as the Git provider, connect to Bitbucket using my credentials (I am admin on the Bitbucket repo), and select the desired Bitbucket repo. Then when I click the "Connect selected repository" I get about a 30s delay and finally a simple "Failed to connect repositories" error message with no further explanation as to why. GCP logging shows nothing.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have enabled the source repos API. Retrospectively I guess this is obvious, because the Bitbucket webhooks need to call out to Google's API to announce when changes occur on the repo.

The GCP API is called Cloud Source Repositories API, and the service name is sourcerepo.googleapis.com

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sourcerepo.googleapis.com

Comment: Apologies for the delay, its been a few weeks since I've had a chance to circle back and start working on this again. You were correct it was just a matter of enabling the API. Thanks for the help!